# GridView Header Click

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I am trying to figure out how to point a Grid View Header Click to my Viewmodel

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserProfileData}" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="Handle_Click">
       <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="User ID"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastUsed}" Header="Last Loaded"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsLoaded}" Header="Logged In"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

GridViewColumnHeader.Click="Handle_Click" will push it to my MainWindow.xaml.cs but i want to have the click go to the DataContext of my MainWindow

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a style to bind the `Command` property of the `GridViewColumnHeader` to an `ICommand` source property of your view model. You could then pass the header `string` as the argument to the command:

```
<ListView x:Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding UserProfileData}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding YourCommandProperty}" />
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Header="User ID"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastUsed}" Header="Last Loaded"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsLoaded}" Header="Logged In"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference of 2 assemblies:

```
System.Windows.Interactivity
Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
```

Add following namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserProfileData}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="User ID">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnClick"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastUsed}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Last Loaded">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnClick"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsLoaded}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Logged In">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnClick"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

In view model, put following method:

```
public void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```